# How do you cite in MLA? (I've forgotten)

Tags: citations, citation-style, self-citation

Am I supposed to cite with quotations around the *author's name*, or quotations then the *author's name*. (I felt like this was obvious but I've seen multiple people site differently, and one of them has to be incorrect, I also have cited MLA in a long time)

Ex. "quote (authors name)" or "quote" (authors name)

And when I say according to this website, does anything change about the citation or am I just supposed to cite the *author's name* like usual.

Also when I don't say which website I'm citing from, can I just say the *author's name* or do I have to change my citing to the websites name...

Ex. (authors name) or (websites name)

Also would I cite a statement like recently *Katy Perry has been on tour, and during her tour ...*

Comment: Why don't you Google this? Takes less time than writing this question... https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_and_style_guide.html

Comment: Use Mendeley or Zotero or endnote. If you can learn to use latex.

Answer (score -3):

These are the 3 citations I saw on Purdue. So its "quote" (authors name) and website after you mention author already

Wordsworth stated that Romantic poetry was marked by a "spontaneous overflow of powerful feelings" (263).

Romantic poetry is characterized by the "spontaneous overflow of powerful feelings" (Wordsworth 263).

Wordsworth extensively explored the role of emotion in the creative process (263).